# How to retrieve django many to many field with list of subscribed objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

users on my project can subscribe model Board and I try to show all objects from all subscribed boards who user subscribe.

But don't know how. I search through internet but nothing help me in this.

Model board:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Tytuł')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    image = ImageField(blank=True, manual_crop="" ,verbose_name='Tło')
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Opis kategorii')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed_boards', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Models related to(I try to show this objects from subscribed boards):

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Tytuł')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    body = HTMLField(blank=True, verbose_name='Treść')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='subject', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects', verbose_name='Kategoria')
    votes = GenericRelation(LikeDislike, related_query_name='subjectsvotes')

class Embed(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Tytuł')
    description = HTMLField(verbose_name='Opis')
    thumbnail_url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    html = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='embeds', verbose_name='Kategoria')
    votes = GenericRelation(LikeDislike, related_query_name='embedvotes')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
```

In view I try this:

```
def feed(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
    feed = user.subscribed_boards.all()
    embeds = feed.filter(embed__in=feed)
    return render(request, 'boards/feed.html',
                {'feed': feed,
                'embeds': embeds})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular reference from `feed` to `feed` in you current code. The actually required code is a lot simpler:

`boards = user.subscribed_boards.prefetch_related('embeds')`

You can now loop over the boards and the embeds in the boards:

```
for board in boards:
    print(board.title)
    for embed in board.embeds.all():
        print(embed.title)
```

The above is Python code to show how to access the objects; you would more likely want to do the loops in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
def feed(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
    feed = user.subscribed_boards.all()
    embeds = user.subscribed_boards.filter(embed__in=feed)
    return render(request, 'boards/feed.html',
                {'feed': feed,
                'embeds': embeds})
```

Please check if it works.